# AngularJS: how to add a special option called "ADD NEW VALUE..." in drop down list?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a drop downlist containing 3 items like below:

```
100
200
300
```

It's very easy to be done using AngularJS.

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="selectedNumber"
        ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in myNumbers">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.myNumbers= [
    { label: '100', value: 100 },
    { label: '200', value: 200 },
    { label: '300', value: 300 }
];

$scope.selectedNumber = $scope.myNumbers[0];
```

Now a new requirement is to add a special option in the drop downlist,

```
Add New Value ...
100
200
300
```

When 'Add New Value ...' is selected a new dialog should show to allow user to add a new value in the drop downlist.

How can I implement such drop downlist?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/OV36RS70HKyO1hxiGcvH?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

why don't you create options yourself like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedNumber">
    <option>Add New Value</option>
    <option ng-repeat="opt in myNumbers">{{opt.label}}</option>
</select>
```

or alternatively create a function that returns your array with extra element for example:

```
$scope.selectNumbers = function() {
    return [{ label: 'Add New Value', value: -1 }].concat($scope.myNumbers.concat_;
}
```

and bind it to select like this

```
<select ng-model="selectedNumber"
        ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in selectNumbers()">
```

Comment: Many thanks! Maybe the first choice is better, because -1 is also a valid number to add by user.

Comment: I'd like the first one better too, but if you'd like to use second one and -1 is correct value use `null` instead

Comment: Is it possible to make the original value still be chosen? For exmple, if value 300 is selected, then user selects 'Add New Value', the result should be: 300 is still be selected, also an AddNewValue dialog shows.

Comment: How To Open Dailog Box when Click on "  Add New " Button